# Computed property based on vuex state not triggering watcher when state change

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have two components: Sales and Quantity. In each component there is DateRange component which allows the user to select a date range.

There are two display modes: general mode where changing date range in one component doesn't affect the other component. Single mode where changing date range in `Sales` should change the date range in `Quantity` component.

The DateRange component is based on v-calendar to offer a nice calendar, then through a computed property `dateRange` I can parse the start and end date of the selected range in v-calendar into a format I can use (`YYYY-MM-DD`) in the backend).

In order to achieve this kind of synchronisation between the `Sales` and `Quantity` component, I'm using a Vuex store with the `product_custom_range` , in case the single mode (through a prop called `singleProduct`) is activated then use the value from the store, otherwise just parse the selected range and return it. So if the value in the store is changed then the computed property in both components will change.

However, I need also to emit an event when this computed property changes in the `DateRange` component, but the watcher is not working, **Even though `dateRange` property is changing in both components successfully**

**Note:** `dateRange` is a computed property, `range` is just a local state variable used by v-calendar defined in `data`

Here's the code :

```
computed: {
    dateRange: function(){
        let dateRangeObj = {}
        
        if(this.singleProduct){
            dateRangeObj = this.$store.state.product_custom_range
        }
        else{
            if(this.range != null){
             dateRangeObj["start"] = moment(this.range.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
             dateRangeObj["end"] = moment(this.range.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            }

        }
    
        console.log("Date range ",dateRangeObj)
        console.log("From store: ",this.$store.state.product_custom_range)
        
        return dateRangeObj
        
    }
},
methods:{
    selectRange(){
        console.log(this.dateRange)
        
        if(this.singleProduct){
            let dateRangeObj = {
                start: moment(this.range.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                end: moment(this.range.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            }
            this.$store.commit("changeProductCustomRange",dateRangeObj)
            
        }
        
        
        this.$emit("dateRangeSelected",this.dateRange)
    }
```

The watcheris just a simple one for now that should log "Watcher is working":

```
    dateRange:{
        handler: function(o,n){
            console.log("Date range changed")
        },
        deep: true
    }
```

Here is the code for the mutation and the initial value in the store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    product_custom_range:{},
  },
  mutations: {
    changeProductCustomRange(state,payload){
        // Used to synchrnize custom ranges
        state.product_custom_range["start"] = payload.start
        state.product_custom_range["end"] = payload.end
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please show the mutation for `changeProductCustomRange` as well as the default value of whatever is being mutated within `changeProductCustomRange`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy just edited it

Comment: Did you put the watch in `watch`?